# How to invoke Java web service using c# client

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

How to invoke Java web service using c# client (https authentication , signing & encrypting soap message is required.
any suggestions please?

Comment: I think you ask about `WS-security` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996951.aspx

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code that you've tried and errors/issues you're having. Thanks!

Comment: Thank  you  Max Poshusta , thats exactelly what im looking for,still only "Message encryption" not mentioned in your post can you help please?